# Codeception get environment on which tests are running

Tags: php, phpunit, codeception

```
I have acceptance.suite.yml which looks like this.

class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - \Helper\Acceptance
        - WebDriver:
             url: https://staging.needhelp.com                 
env:
    firefox:
         modules:
            config:
                qa_user: qauser1@gmail.com
                WebDriver:
                    browser: 'firefox'
                    capabilities:
                        platform: Windows 7

    chrome:
         modules:
            config:
                qa_user: qauser2@gmail.com
                WebDriver:
                    browser: 'chrome'
                    capabilities:
                        platform: Windows 8.1
```

And I run the test case as so:

```
$ codecept run acceptance UserCest.php --env firefox --env chrome
```

Now, I was wondering if there is a way to get env within test itself during run time.

```
class UserCest extends BaseAcceptance
{



    public function login(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->amOnPage("/");
        $I->see('Sign In');
        $env = $I->getConfig('env'); 
//something like this ?? which would return 'firefox' for the instance it is running as environment firefox. 

        $I->fillField($this->usernameField, $this->username);
        $I->fillField($this->passwordField, $this->password);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to access that info via `scenario`. As it is said in the [docs](http://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage#Current-values):

> You can access \Codeception\Scenario in Cept and Cest formats. In Cept $scenario variable is availble by default, while in Cests you should receive it through dependency injection.

So in your case it should look something like this:

```
public function login(AcceptanceTester $I, \Codeception\Scenario $scenario)
{
    $I->amOnPage("/");
    $I->see('Sign In');

    if ($scenario->current('browser') == 'firefox') {
        //code to handle firefox
    }

    $I->fillField($this->usernameField, $this->username);
    $I->fillField($this->passwordField, $this->password);
}
```